# Is there a way to format the widgets' contents?

Tags: bokeh

Let's say I'd like to underline a word in one of my options in a RadioButtonGroup, is it possible?

I tried to use the Div class as an input, but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This PR ["Add support for specifying CSS classes on all LayoutDOM"](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/5503) will be going into Bokeh `0.12.4` in Dec 2017 and provided a mechanism to add arbitrary CSS classes to any Bokeh `LayoutDOM` model (e.g. widgets) so that they can be more easily styled.

It will be available like:

```
from bokeh.models import Div
div = Div(text="some text")

# add these CSS classes to the widget div 
div.css_classes = ["my-custom"]
```

Then you can add styles for `.my-custom` in your template or whatever.

Comment: FYI this PR has been merged and the feature is available in the "dev build" `0.12.4dev7`

Comment: Thanks. Plz elaborate further on the 'whatever' part: I serve the document through "bokeh serve" and see an empty `<style></style>` pair of tags in the `<head>`. How do I populate it?