# bokeh layout for plot and widget arrangement

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a specific design in mind for my bokeh app. I am using `bokeh 0.12.3` and a bokeh server to keep everything in sync. Please, have a look at my mockup:

[image]

On the left-hand side, there is a static navigation bar, the right part of the view will consist of plots, that are manually added. The amount of plot columns on the right-hand side shall change w.r.t. window size. I am well aware of the bokeh layout documentation [laying out plots and widgets](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html), but it's a bit more complicated. This is the layout I currently have:

```
doc_layout = layout(children=[[column(radio_buttons,
                                      cbx_buttons,
                                      div,
                                      data_table,
                                      plot,
                                      button)]],
                    sizing_mode='scale_width')
curdoc().add_root(doc_layout)
```

In order to add new plots I use:

```
doc_layout.children[-1].children.append(plot)
# appends plot to layout children [[column(..), plot]]
```

But the behavior is very strange, and not at all what I actually want to achieve. New plots are added on top of the column (menu panel) instead.

Here, a short example where you can try out to see what I mean:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox, column, row

WIDTH = 200
HEIGHT = 200

def add_plot():
    p = figure(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, tools=[], toolbar_location=None)
    p.line([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25])
    doc_layout.children[-1].children.append(p)

src = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]))
t1 = DataTable(source=src, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT,
               columns=[TableColumn(field='x', title='x'),
                        TableColumn(field='y', title='y')])
b = Button(label='add plot')
b.on_click(add_plot)

doc_layout = layout([[widgetbox(b, t1)]], sizing_mode='scale_width')
curdoc().add_root(doc_layout)
```

I am not sure what is the best solution to overcome this problem. I've tried several things, from `layout()` with different sizing modes, `gridplot()`, `column()`/`row()` in different combinations. In my previous version, where the navigation menu was placed on the top of the page instead on the left-hand side, everything seemed to work:

```
layout(children=[[widgetbox(radio_button, cbx_button),
                  widgetbox(data_table),
                  widgetbox(div),
                  widgetbox(button)],
                  [Spacer()]],
       sizing_mode='scale_width')
```

Comment: I'm fighting with a very similar problem as we speak :)

Comment: Well, the most comfortable way to do it would be with:
`row(column(.., sizing_mode='fixed'), layout(.., sizing_mode='scale_width'))`
But sizing modes are overwritten by the top layout, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the last line in your callback to:

```
doc_layout.children[0].children[-1].children.append(p)
```

And change your layout to:

```
doc_layout = layout(sizing_mode='scale_width') 
doc_layout.children.append(row(column(widgetbox(b, t1)), column()))
```

But then then don't propagate exactly as you'd like. I think for that you would need to do some custom css styling.

Assuming yours is a [directory format](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#directory-format) app, one option would be to make a `template/index.html` file where you can add a `style` block in the header where you could try to override css to make your plots `inline-block`s or something.

```
<style>
  .bk-whatever-class {
    ...
  }
</style>
```

Use a developer tool on your browser to find the appropriate classes and toy with them. But perhaps not the best solution....

For widgets there is a [`css_classes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982923/943773) attribute, where you could specify a class for that widget to use, but that unfortunately doesn't help with the plot canvases.

```
mycol = column(css_classes=['myclass'])
```