# Resizing Bokeh Dropdowns and other Widgets

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

How can I adjust the size of a dropdown or other widgets with Bokeh in Python?

I have the following dropdowns acting as filters on a graphic:

[image]

As you can see, they're all different lengths. They're in a widgetbox like this:

```
widgets = widgetbox([school_selector,
                degree_selector,
                student_selector,
                began_exam_selector,
                finished_exam_selector],
                sizing_mode='fixed')
```

which gets dropped into the final layout like this:

```
dashboard_layout = column(widgets, column(time_v_note, exam_data_table))
curdoc().add_root(dashboard_layout)
```

I have tried `'fixed'`, `'scale_width'`, and `'stretch_both'` as options for `sizing_mode` but nothing has change. I just want all the filters to be the same size so there's no jagged edge.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here's what the Select() construction looks like:

```
#### School Selector
## Selection Options
school_select_opts = ['All'] + list(exam_df['School ID - School Name'].unique())

## Selector Build
school_selector = Select(title='1) Choose a School:',
                         options=school_select_opts,
                         value='All')

#### Degree Selector
## Selection Options
degree_select_opts = ['All'] + list(exam_df['Degree'].unique())

## Selector Build
degree_selector = Select(title='2) Choose a Degree:',
                         options=degree_select_opts,
                         value='All')

#### Exam Selector
## Selection Options
exam_select_opts = ['All'] + list(exam_df['Exam ID - Exam Name'].unique())

## Selector Build
exam_selector = Select(title='3) Choose an Exam:',
                       options=exam_select_opts,
                       value='All')

#### Student Selector
## Selection Options
student_select_opts = ['All'] + list(exam_df['Applicant ID - Full Name'].unique())

## Selector Build
student_selector = Select(title='4) Choose a Student:',
                         options=student_select_opts,
                         value='All')

#### Begin Exam Selector
## Selection Options
begin_exam_opts = ['All', 'Yes', 'No']

## Selector Build
began_exam_selector = Select(title='Began Exam?',
                             options=begin_exam_opts,
                             value='All')

#### Finished Exam Selector
## Selection Options
finished_exam_opts = ['All', 'Yes', 'No']

## Selector Build
finished_exam_selector = Select(title='Finished Exam?',
                                options=finished_exam_opts,
                                value='All')
```

Comment: are you passing a `width` parameter to the `Select` constructor? I made a quick test. Without `width` anywhere, `sizing_mode='fixed'` on the `widgetbox` I get everything aligned (bokeh 0.12.9).

Comment: @Alex No, I wasn't passing any kind of width parameter. I didn't even think that was an option. I edited the question to include all my Select() calls. I tried adding a width parameter to some of the Select calls just to see what would happen and there was no change.

Comment: ok, so i could reproduce it (need really long strings to trigger). Unfortunately no easy solutions. I see three ways: 1/ use `width` (but set `sizing_mode` to `fixed` otherwise, that overrides `width`) but that's pretty manual tuning, 2/ you can pass a css class to `Select` so I guess it's possible to do something that way but no experience myself.

Comment: @Alex thanks for the help. I had tried using the width but it wasn't working, but I realize now after reading your comment about long strings that it's because the width I was specifying was too short and the Selectors can't be shorter than the longest string, at least with this strategy. Do you have any good references for passing a css class?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981485/is-there-a-way-to-format-the-widgets-contents) and [this](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/5503). Never used it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Just write down width and mention it's value and you will get the required answer.

**Code**:

```
menu = [("Delhi", "3"), ("Mumbai", "4"), ("Chennai", "4"), ("Kochi", "6"), ("Kolkata", "7")]

dropdown = Dropdown(label="LOCATION", button_type="success", menu=menu,width=120)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to a folder app with custom templates

Let's say you have a `my_app` folder:

in `my_app/main.py` (it has to be named main.py):

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import Select

curdoc().add_root(widgetbox([Select(title=str(i)+') Select:',options=['']+['a'*i*10],css_classes=['my_inputs']) for i in range(10)],css_classes=['my_widgetbox']))
```

in `my_app/templates/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {{ bokeh_css }}
    {{ bokeh_js }}
  </head>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
      {% include 'styles.css' %}
    </style>
    {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
    {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
  </body>
</html>
```

in `my_app/templates/styles.css` :

```
.my_widgetbox div.bk-widget.bk-layout-fixed.my_inputs {
    width:300px;
}
```

If you run that (`bokeh serve --show my_app` in the same directory as `my_app`) you will notice that the first 4 widgets have the specified length of 300 px. But the next widgets have options that are longer than 300px themselves so the widget will extended to fit the largest option in that case. I don't know how to prevent that.

You could shorten the option strings, or make all the widgets as wide as the widest one.

To figure out how to get elements in the document, like the `div.bk-widget.bk-layout-fixed` part, I just check out elements using the console in the browser.